# How to get the session value outside of folder using php

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-variables, session-cookies

I have 3 different sites but single login for all websites. All site files are stored in separate separate folders. Like this

```
example.com   ----- 1st Site
example.com/hotel -----  2nd Site
example.com/bus  ------  3rd Site
```

When i login any one website i need to auto login for all websites. so only i need to get the session value outside of folder. Is this possible? if is this possible please guide me.

Comment: `session_set_cookie_params(0, '/','example.com'); ` before the session_start()

Comment: Please give me some example?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php check in the manual how it works for subdomains.